# If two pullback bundles are equivalent, must the maps be homotopic?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, pullback

Let $E \to M$ be a fiber bundle and $f,g \colon N \to M$.

- We know (e.g. from Steerod) that if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, then the pullback bundles are equivalent bundles over $N$, $f^\ast E \cong g^\ast E$.
- What about the reverse implication? If we assume that $f^\ast E \cong g^\ast E$, in what cases does this imply that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic?

Comment: Surely letting $E$ be the trivial bundle on $N$ gives counter-example?

Comment: The case where this is naturally true is when $M$ is the classifying space for the respective type of fiber bundle.

Comment: Thanks @krm2233, yes I suppose I am looking for general conditions (e.g. $E$ not trivial) such that the implication holds.

Comment: @Thorgott can you expand a bit on that?

Comment: The classifying $BG$ is equipped with a universal bundle such that every fiber bundle with structure group $G$ on a space $M$ is (under mild technical conditions) the pullback of this universal bundle by a unique homotopy class of maps $M\rightarrow BG$. More generally, using this, the property you want to hold for all $N$ is equivalent to asking that the map $M\rightarrow BG$ classifying $E$ is a monomorphism in the homotopy category. These are incredibly hard to understand.